# Google Drive list API - Empty list

Tags: google-drive-api, drive, google-apis-explorer, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using [google drive list api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list). For one G-Suite domain I get empty list. I tried in API explorer, same result.

Tried for another G-Suite domain, I get response as described in the documentation, works both in API explorer and my code.

What is it I am missing here?

[image: Empty list][image: Expected response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The method `Drives: list` lists only the **shared** drives of a Google Drive user.
- If the resulting list is empty, this means that there is no shared drive associated with the given account
- To create a new shared drive, follow the corresponding [instructions](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310249?hl=en)
- After successfully creating a shared drive, it will show up in the results of  `Drives: list`

Comment: You have a typo *rsulting* -> *resulting*